# no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<double*, std::allocator<double*> >::push_back(double&)

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to push 3 values (posx, posy, posz here) as the 0th-2nd elements of the vector atomPosRow_ and 3 values (velx, vely, velz) as the 0th-2nd elements of atomVelRow_. Eventually, I will be updating the size and content of these vectors.

I know I can just pass them in my main function but I wanted to have the function that does this as a part of the"Particle" class. At this point I am getting the error:  no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(double&). I believe I am not giving the right arguments to getRow but not sure where the error is coming from.

I am really sorry if this is a very trivial question, I am very new to object oriented programming and have been looking into this for the last two days and still could not figure it out.

Thanks so much in advance.

myheader.h

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::if
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

   class Particle {
   private:
    vector<double> boxLower_;
    vector<double> boxUpper_;
    vector< vector<double> > atomPos_;
    vector< vector<double> > atomVel_;
    int atomNumber_;
    double radius_;
  public:
    Particle(int atomNumber, double radius, vector<double> boxLower, vector<double> boxUpper, vector< vector<double> > atomPos, vector< vector<double> > atomVel);
    ~Particle();
    int getRow(double posx, double posy, double posz, double velx, double vely, double velz, vector<double*> atomPosRow, vector<double*> atomVelRow);
};`
```

myfunction.cpp

```
#include "myheader.h"
Particle::Particle(int atomNumber, double radius, vector<double> boxLower, vector<double> boxUpper, vector< vector<double> > atomPos, vector< vector<double> > atomVel)
  : atomNumber_(atomNumber),
    radius_(radius),
    boxLower_(boxLower),
    boxUpper_(boxUpper),
    atomPos_(atomPos),
    atomVel_(atomVel)
{}

Particle::~Particle()
{}

int Particle::getRow(double posx, double posy, double posz, double velx, double vely, double velz, vector<double*> atomPosRow, vector<double*> atomVelRow) {
  atomPosRow.push_back(posx); // Add an element (column) to the row
  atomPosRow.push_back(posy);
  atomPosRow.push_back(posz);
  atomVelRow.push_back(velx);
  atomVelRow.push_back(vely);
  atomVelRow.push_back(velz);
return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <fstream>    
#include <vector>
#include "myheader.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
double xlow, ylow, zlow, xup, yup, zup;

vector<double> boxLower_;
vector<double> boxUpper_;
vector< vector<double> > atomPos_;
vector< vector<double> > atomVel_;

ifstream inputFile("data.txt");
int atomNumber_;
double radius_;
inputFile >> atomNumber_ >> radius_;
inputFile >> xlow >> ylow >> zlow;
inputFile >> xup >> yup >> zup;

boxLower_.push_back(xlow);
boxLower_.push_back(ylow);
boxLower_.push_back(zlow);
boxUpper_.push_back(xup);
boxUpper_.push_back(yup);
boxUpper_.push_back(zup);

double posx = 0;
double posy = 0;
double posz = 0;
double velx = 0;
double vely = 0;
double velz = 0;

Particle *assignParticles;
assignParticles = new Particle(atomNumber_, radius_, boxLower_, boxUpper_, atomPos_, atomVel_);

while (inputFile >> posx >> posy >> posz >> velx >> vely >> velz)
{
  vector<double*> atomPosRow_;
  vector<double*> atomVelRow_;
  assignParticles->getRow(posx, posy, posz, velx, vely, velz, atomPosRow_, atomVelRow_);
  //atomPos_.push_back(atomPosRow_); // Add the row to the main vector
  //atomVel_.push_back(atomVelRow_);
}
inputFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atomPosRow_` is of type `vector<double*>` while `atomPos_` expects `vector<double>`.

Comment: You have a vector of double pointers, so you need to push_back a double pointer. Use the address-of operator (`&`) to get one. There is *way* too much code here for me to read. You should be able to get this down to only a few lines that demonstrate the problem; see our guidance on preparing an [MCVE].

Comment: 1. Try to start off with a good textbook and read about *pointers*, *references* and *values*. Your code has serveral fundamental flaws. (i.e. you pass a vector by value to a function and push_back into it while not using the result anywhere). 2. Don't use `new` in `C++` (especially not without `delete`!).